# how to load mainclass of jar file called from resource

Tags: java

I am write some line in java to run jar file from resource in runtime

first i get the jar fill

> ```
> // create FileInputStream object
> InputStream fileInputStream = TestCL.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jar");
> ```

Create byte array

> ```
> byte rawBytes[] = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
> ```

To read content of the file in byte array

> ```
> fileInputStream.read(rawBytes);
> ```

how i can load main class from this fileInputStream

---

this is my test to call method from class, how i can make this example with jar file ?

```
package testcl;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class TestCL extends ClassLoader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        TestCL javaClassLoader = new TestCL();
        javaClassLoader.load();

    }

    public void load() throws Exception {

        // create FileInputStream object
        InputStream fileInputStream = TestCL.class.getResourceAsStream("ClassLoaderInput.class");
        byte rawBytes[] = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
        fileInputStream.read(rawBytes);

        // Load the target class
        Class<?> regeneratedClass = this.defineClass(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.length);

        // Getting a method from the loaded class and invoke it
        regeneratedClass.getMethod("printString", null).invoke(regeneratedClass.newInstance(), null);
    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of "load"? Load as usable class via `ClassLoader` or load the bytes? (a jar is a zip file, you can use plain old zip code to look into it)

Comment: ys bro, with ClassLoader but without create file in HDD and call it with url or other

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html - the `Url` might be `TestCL.class.getResource("test.jar")`, not sure about that. Cound also be that you have to prefix that url with `jar:`

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the class and invoke the main method or just try to run it from cmd.

Try this code:

```
    Class<?>[] cArgs = new Class[1]; 
    cArgs[0] = java.lang.String.class;
    URL url = new URL("// enter the .jar path");
    URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    InputStream fileInputStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("test.jar");
    Method mainMethod = cl.loadClass("//enter class name").getMethod("main", cArgs[0]);
```

Comment: ok how i can get the main class ? I deal with InputStream obj

Comment: look my test class bro